# pwa javascript video recording app for all browsers including safari in 2021

Tags: javascript, video, recording

There are a lot of information and tutorials on this topic, all are outdated or don't work on IOS.

Is there a way to record video with audio in a pwa using Safari and chrome browser? Please if you can give me example or a tutorial to follow that works for both, or offers a workaround for Safari and chrome.

What i have tried works on everything, but on IPHONE i get black screen, or media type not supported. I tried recordRTC.js, and a tutorial with VIDEO.js and VIDEO-record.js all posed the same issue.

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED IT:
Not quite the result i wanted but it works for my needs.

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="dealWithVideo(this);" accept="video/*" capture="camera" id="vidrec">
```